# How to create chain of processes in C?

Tags: c

I need to create 5 processes one being father of the second, grandpa of the  third etc. All of them have to wait for each other to finish. I tried the approach with:

```
switch (pid = fork()) {
  case 0: 
    printf("Child PID = %d\n", getpid());
    printf("parent: =\%d\n", getppid());
    return 0;

default:
  break;
```

But I always get the same parent.

Comment: The *all* have to wait for *each other*? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think he means that the parent waits for the child to finish.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant

Comment: @JossieCalderon: Yes, but as they are in a direct relation, that is exactly what KerrekSB wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use recursion.

For example:

```
void create_processes(int n) {
  if(n == 0) return;
  if(fork() == 0) {
    int status;

    // You're in the child process. Calling it recursively will have the
    // child's PID as parent
    create_processes(n - 1);

    // Do work you need done before the child terminates
    wait(&status);
    // Do work you need done after the child terminates
  } 
}
```

Then call it like

```
create_processes(5);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works way better, but from getppid() I sometimes get 1 and sometimes get PID-1 from child PID. Is there a way to fight this? Where should I put the wait() function?

Comment: @cAMPy I've updated my answer to include the `wait()`.

Answer (score 0):

Call a process `myProcess` that returns no type and takes an `int` as a parameter. Then...

```
void myProcess(int x) 
{ 
if (x > 5) return;
if (x != 0)
    myProcess(x - 1);
return;
};

int main()
{
int myvar = 5;
myProcess(myvar);
return 0;
}
```

It's done recursively.